# how to add my custom productcockpit extension as one of the options in hybris backoffice perspectives list mainslot

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a customproductcockpit extension created and web module enabled.
i.e different URl to access localhost:9002/customproductcockpit.
Now I want to add this in Backoffice main slot as one of the perspective options.
Can some one please help me on this.
As shown in image I want to add one more option along with Administration and ProductCockpit.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you wish to add custom perspective in the back office, then you need to add another context in -backoffice-config.xml.

Sample Example:

```
 <!--    start of employeemanager-->
    <context merge-by="principal" component="explorer-tree" module="<custombackoffice extension name>" principal="employeemanager">
        <explorer-tree:explorer-tree>
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="backoffice_dashboard" merge-mode="remove"/>
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_backoffice-workflow-inbox" merge-mode="remove"/>
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_system" merge-mode="remove"/>
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_catalog" merge-mode="remove"/>
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_medias" merge-mode="remove"/>

            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_user" expanded-by-default="true" merge-mode="replace">
                <explorer-tree:type-node code="UserGroup" id="hmc_typenode_usergroup" />
                <explorer-tree:type-node code="Employee" id="hmc_typenode_employee"/>
            </explorer-tree:navigation-node>

            
        </explorer-tree:explorer-tree>
    </context>
    <!--    end of employeemanager-->
```